# Symfony2 forms - structured data to flat entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to map this data by SF2 form

```
[
   'name' => 'XL',
   'dimensions' => [
       'width' => 50,
       'height' => 20,
       'length' => 20,
    ]
]
```

to the entity

```
Box[name, width, height, length]
```

Something like:

```
$builder->add('dimensions.width', 'text', [
    'property_path' => 'width'
])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version no. The `dimensions` array key above would have to be an [embedded form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms), however you could set the data class to be the same object which would (probably) work. E.g.

```
class DimensionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('width')->add('height')->add('length');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 'data_class' => 'MyClass' ]);
    }
}

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')->add('dimension', new DimensionType(), [ 'mapped' => false, 'data' => $options['data'] ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 'data_class' => 'MyClass' ]);
    }
}
```

So you have two form types, one of which is embedded in the other. For `MyFormType`, the `dimension` field isn't mapped to `MyClass`, however it has the same `data_class` option which means when the form resolves it should set the `width`, `height` and `length` properties on the object.

I haven't tested this but in theory this should work. Ideally you'd change the submitted data to match your object (as Symfony forms are only views of your objects) but this might be a decent patch.